# Two step form with database send. With a big post array

Tags: javascript, php

Let me explain first how this script works. In the step 0 we enter the data ( list number, min-max value). The script counts the range and pushes an array with the number values. (min + 1 until max value is reached).

Then it's sent to step 1. This is a preview site. It shows min, max value, range and each number.

Step 2 is sending to database (on press submit). This script was working smoothly without the step implementation. But after setting the step system I lose somehow the array of numbers and all data before sending it to database (step 2 doesn't get step 1 values somehow). The range can be upto 2k values most likely less. I'm concerned if there is a way not to have them values displayed in url to get them into the other steps, because these numbers will have 24 numerical each so the url could be really long. Can you share with me any ideas how it could be fixed? And how to retrieve the step 1 values into step 2 (db sending). Thanks.

```
<?PHP

  if (!defined("_VALID_PHP"))
      die('Direct access to this location is not allowed.');
    $db_handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=proj2', 'root', '');
ini_set('memory_limit', '2000M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '600M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '640M');
$step = 0;
$msg = array();
?>

<?php

if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
if($_GET['error']== 2){
 echo $core->msgError("<span>Alert!</span>List has over (2000) entries.",false); 
 }
if($_GET['error']== 1){
 echo $core->msgError("<span>Alert!</span>List already exists.",false); 
 }

 }

unset($_POST['submit']);
unset($sub_items);
unset($_POST['mainItem']);

?>
        <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
        <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){




            $("#low").keydown(function(event){
            if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 ) {
                    // let it happen, don't do anything
            }else if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57 ) {
                event.preventDefault(); 
            }
            var remainingChars = $(this).val().length;
            if (remainingChars == 24) {
                $(this).attr('readonly','readonly');
            }
        });
        $("#high").keydown(function(event){
            if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 ) {
                    // let it happen, don't do anything
            }else if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57 ) {
                event.preventDefault(); 
            }
            var remainingChars = $(this).val().length;
            if (remainingChars == 24) {
                $(this).attr('readonly','readonly');
            }
        });
        $("#ln").keydown(function(event){
            if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 ) {
                    // let it happen, don't do anything
            }else if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57 ) {
                event.preventDefault(); 
            }
            var remainingChars = $(this).val().length;
            if (remainingChars == 24) {
                $(this).attr('readonly','readonly');
            }
        });

    $("#DueDate").datepicker();
    $( "#DueDate" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd" + " " + getCurrentTime() );

function getCurrentTime() {
    var CurrentTime = "";
    try {
        var CurrentDate = new Date();
        var CurrentHours = CurrentDate.getHours();
        var CurrentMinutes = CurrentDate.getMinutes();

        CurrentTime = "" + CurrentHours + ":" + CurrentMinutes +"";
    }
    catch (ex) {
    }
    return CurrentTime;
}
    });



    </script>
    <?PHP if(isset($_POST['analizuj']) && $_POST['step']=='1'){
    if($_POST['high'] == NULL || $_POST['ln'] == NULL || $_POST['DueDate'] == NULL || $_POST['low'] == NULL){
header('location: index.php?do=bulkadd');
echo $core->msgError("<span>Alert!</span>Fields ListNumber,Range,Date cant be empty.",false);
}else{
        $liczba_a=$_POST['high'];
        $liczba_b=$_POST['low'];
        $numbers = array($liczba_a, $liczba_b);
        $min = min($numbers);
        $max = max($numbers);

        $a = round(bcsub($max, $min)).'<br>';
        $diffcap = round($a);

        if($a > 2000){ header('location: index.php?do=bulkadd&error=2'); exit();
        }else{
        $size=range(0,$diffcap);
        //$i = 0;
        $count = round($diffcap);

        $array= array();

        $i=0;
        foreach ($size as &$value) {
            array_push($array, preg_replace('/^([^.]*).*$/', '$1',bcadd($min, $i)));
            $i++;
        }
        if(count($array) > 2000){ header('location: index.php?do=bulkadd&error=2'); exit();}
        }
}


    ?>
      <form id="details" method="post" action="index.php?do=bulkadd">
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="subitemsTbl">
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Min Value : <?PHP echo $min; ?></th>
            <th>Max Value : <?PHP echo $max; ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr cellpadding="2"><td><strong>Range :</strong> <?PHP echo $a; ?></td></tr>

    </tbody>

    </table>
    <br>
    <br>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="subitemsTbl">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Lp</th>
            <th>Number</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr cellpadding="2"><td><input type="submit" value="Send to Db" name="licz" class="button-sml"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="step" value="2" /></td></tr>
    <br>
    <tbody id="body">
    <?PHP
    $fakeid=1;
    foreach($array as $key=>$value) 
    { 
    unset($array[$key + 1]); 
    // Note that there is no $b here.
    echo '<tr id="rowNum'.$fakeid.'"><th>'.$fakeid.'</th><td><input class="inputbox-sml" type="text" name="subItem[]" readonly="readonly" value="'.$value.'" size="24" style="width:210px;"></td></tr>';
    $fakeid++;
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>


<?PHP }else{ ?>
<div id="wrap">
<h1>Range List Generator</h1>
    <form id="details" method="post" action="index.php?do=bulkadd">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Set</legend>
              <strong>On : </strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <select name="forwho" style="width:180px">
         <?PHP
                  $sql = 'SELECT id, name, surname FROM customers ORDER BY name';
                 foreach ($db_handler->query($sql) as $row) {
                    echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['name'] ." ".$row['surname']. "</option>";
                  }
            ?> 
          </select>
          <br>
          <strong>Date :</strong> <input id="DueDate" name="DueDate" style="font-size: 12px;" type="text"  class="inputbox-sml"/><br>
          <strong>ID :</strong> <?PHP echo $user->getID(); ?></fieldset><br>
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Type</legend>
          <strong>Prority : </strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <select name="priority" style="width:180px">
            <option value="0">Normal</option>
            <option value="1">High</option>
          </select><br>
          <strong>List Type :</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <select name="type" style="width:180px">
            <option value="1">K</option>
            <option value="0">N</option>
          </select><br>
          <strong>Letters : </strong><input type="text" name="letters" id="letters" maxlength="4" class="inputbox-sml"/>
    </fieldset><br>
    <strong>List Number: </strong><input type="text" name="ln" id="ln" maxlength="24" class="inputbox-sml" style="width:210px;"/><br/><br/>
    <hr><br>
    <strong>Range : </strong><input type="text" name="high" id="high" maxlength="24" class="inputbox-sml" style="width:210px;"/><br/><br/>
    <strong>Range : </strong> <input type="text" name="low" id="low" maxlength="24" class="inputbox-sml" style="width:210px;"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Analizuj" name="analizuj" class="button-sml"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="step" value="1" />
    <!-- OLD TABLE START -->
    </form>
</div>


<?php

}
if (isset($_POST['licz']) && $_POST['step']=='2') {
if($_POST['high'] == NULL || $_POST['ln'] == NULL || $_POST['DueDate'] == NULL || $_POST['low'] == NULL){
header('location: index.php?do=bulkadd');
echo $core->msgError("<span>Alert!</span>Can't be empty.",false);
}else{
        $liczba_a=$_POST['high'];
        $liczba_b=$_POST['low'];
        $numbers = array($liczba_a, $liczba_b);
        $min = min($numbers);
        $max = max($numbers);

        $a = round(bcsub($max, $min)).'<br>';
        $diffcap = round($a);
        //secure 1
        if($a > 2000){ header('location: index.php?do=bulkadd&error=2'); exit();
        }else{
        $size=range(0,$diffcap);
        //$i = 0;
        $count = round($diffcap);

        $array= array();

        $i=0;
        foreach ($size as &$value) {
            array_push($array, preg_replace('/^([^.]*).*$/', '$1',bcadd($min, $i)));
            $i++;
        }
        if(count($array) > 2000){ header('location: index.php?do=bulkadd&error=2'); exit();}
        }
}
        //Handle main item already exists error
    try {
        $stmt = $db_handler->prepare('SELECT * FROM listy WHERE number=?');
        $stmt->bindValue(1, $_POST['ln'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $row_count = $stmt->rowCount();
        if($row_count > 0){ header('location: index.php?do=bulkadd&error=1'); exit();}
    } catch(PDOException $ex) {
        die($ex->getMessage());
    }

    try {
        $stmt = $db_handler->prepare('INSERT INTO listy (number,letters,forwho,bywho,prority,type,created) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)');
        $stmt->bindValue(1, $_POST['ln'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(2, $_POST['letters'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(3, $_POST['forwho'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(4, $user->getID(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(5, $_POST['priority'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(6, $_POST['type'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(7, $_POST['DueDate'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
    } catch(PDOException $ex) {
        die($ex->getMessage());
    }


    //Insert loop
    $mainRowId = 0;
    $mainRowId = $db_handler->lastInsertId(); 
    $sub_items = array_unique($array);
    //print_r($_POST);
    //print_r($sub_items);
    foreach($sub_items as $this_sub){
    //echo $this_sub;
        try {
            $stmt = $db_handler->prepare('INSERT INTO numbers (`list_id`,`number`,`return`,`date`) VALUES(?,?,?,?)');
            $stmt->bindValue(1, $mainRowId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindValue(2, $this_sub, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(3, 0, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindValue(4, $_POST['DueDate'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();

            $subRowId = 0;
            $subRowId = $db_handler->lastInsertId(); 
            $stmt = $db_handler->prepare('INSERT INTO list_has_number (`list_id`,`number_id`) VALUES(?,?)');
            $stmt->bindValue(1, $mainRowId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindValue(2, $subRowId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();

        } catch(PDOException $ex) {
            die($ex->getMessage());
        }
    }

        //
        //while ($i < $count) {
        //   echo 'array '.$b = bcadd($liczba_a, $i).'<br>';
        //   array_push($array, $b);
        //   ++$i;
        //}
        //var_dump($array);


} else {
       echo "Error";
}

?>
```

Comment: Killer code canvas, I doubt someone eventually will read it

Comment: What you mean by that